# Leaflet.Draw show distance in miles

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

When I draw / edit circles manually on a leaflet map using the draw plugin, their radius is shown in **km** even though I have the below settings which should show the radius in **miles**.

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to get the radius to show in miles?

```
map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topright',
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        circle: {
            metric: true,
            feet: false
        }
    },
    draw: {
        circle: {
            metric: true,
            feet: false
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: To get miles you need `metric: false, feet: false`

Comment: @peeebeee Okay, its fine when I draw a circle, but when I edit and resize it, it shows KM

Comment: Did you change the values for both edit and draw? See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set metric: false and feet: false

```
map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topright',
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        circle: {
            metric: false,
            feet: false
        }
    },
    draw: {
        circle: {
            metric: false,
            feet: false
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: I did this, but upon editing it still shows KM when a circle is resized.